# Entity Attribute Value model (EAV) and how to achieve it with cfml?

Tags: database, coldfusion, entity-attribute-value

[image]

I'm trying to figure out how to implement this relationship in coldfusion. Also if anyone knows the name for this kind of relationship I'd be curious to know it.

I'm trying to create the brown table.

Recreating the table from the values is not the problem, the problem that I've been stuck with for a couple of days now is how to create an editing environment.

I'm thinking that I should have a table with all the Tenants and TenantValues (TenantValues that match TenantID I'm editing) and have the empty values as well  (the green table)

any other suggestions?

Comment: I can't see a brown table anywhere - my desk is light brown, I suppose...

Comment: the one above the green table

Comment: I should also mention, that the problem I see with this solution is that if I want to move to a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship it may not be able to accommodate.

Comment: it might just be me, Daniel - but I don't see an image, both in IE9 and Firefox 4.0.1.

Comment: http://oi55.tinypic.com/14lho28.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of this relationship is called an [Entity Attribute Value model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) (EAV). In your case `Tenant`, `TenantVariable`, `TenantValues` are the entity, attribute and value tables, respectively. EAV is attempt to allow for the runtime definition or entities and is most found in my experience backing content managements systems. It has been referred to an as [anti pattern](http://karwin.blogspot.com/2009/05/eav-fail.html) database model because you lose certain RDBMS advantages, while gaining disadvantages such as having to lock several tables on delete or save. Often a suitable persistence alternative is a NoSQL solution such as [Couch](http://couchdb.apache.org/).

As for edits, the paradigm I typically see is deleting all the value records for a given ID and inserting inside a loop, and then updating the entity table record. **Do this inside of a transaction to ensure consistency**. The upshot of this approach is that it's must easier to figure out than delta detection algorithm. Another option is using the MERGE statement if your database supports it.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider an RDF [Triple Store](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triplestore) for this problem. It's an alternative to Relational DBs that's particularly good for sparse categorical data. The data is represented as triples - *directed graph edges* consisting of a subject, an object, and the predicate that describes the property connecting them:

```
(subject) (predicate) (object)
```

Some example triples from your data set would look something like:

```
<Apple> rdf:type <Red_Fruit>
<Apple> hasWeight "1"^^xsd:integer
```

RDF triple stores provide the SPARQL query language to retrieve data from your store much like you would use SQL.

Comment: +1 because it's interesting idea, but have you actually used any of the implementations?

Comment: @orangepips Yep. I even have a library for doing this with ColdFusion on GitHub ( https://github.com/bpanulla/semantic-fu ). I use the open source Apache Jena triple store, but I've also used Mulgara ( http://www.mulgara.org ) for a past project.